# React JS - How to set state of variable inside variable?

Tags: reactjs, state

I want to set state of this form :

```
this.state = {
  filter: {
    search: null,
    brands: null,
    price: null
  }
}
```

How to set value for search / brands / price ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following:

```
this.setState({
  filter: {
    search: 'value',
    brands: 'value',
    price: 'value'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The key is that you don't want to ever mutate a value in state. As a result, you must copy the filter object before passing it to setState. Example:

```
onSearchChange(value) {
  this.setState((state) => {
    return {
       filter: {
         ...state.filter,
         search: value
       }
  })
}
```

Note that I am passing a function to setState. Since the next value of state relies on the previous value, you want to use an updater functions, [as the setState docs recommend](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

In general, it is nicer if you can keep your state flat. So rather than having a filter object in state, your shape could just be

```
this.state = {
   search: null,
   brands: null,
   price: null,
}
```

In which case the above onSearchChange function would just be

```
onSearchChange(value) {
  this.setState({search: value})
}
```

Definitely a lot easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend avoiding nested objects and keeping your state flat. e.g.

```
this.state = {
  brandsFilter: null,
  priceFilter: null,
  searchFilter: null,
};
```

Component state in react is really nothing more than simple key-value pairs; that's what `setState` supports. Sure you can have nested objects if you really want. But as the other answers demonstrate, supporting such an approach can be needlessly complex.

Answer (score 1):

you should use the setState function, you can set the filter with updated data like so

```
const newFilter = {...};
this.setState({filter: newFilter});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid to mutate React state directly, there are some functions can do immutable jobs for you (ex `Object.assign`):

```
const currentFilter = this.state.filter;
const newFilter = Object.assign({}, currentFilter, {search: "new search", brands: [], price: 100});
this.setState({filter: newFilter});
```

ES 6:

```
const currentFilter = this.state.filter;
this.setState({
   filter: {
      ...currentFilter,
      search: "new search",
      brands: []
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.setState({
filter: {
      ...this.state.filter,
      search: "new search", 
      brands: 'value',
      price: 'value'
   }
});
```

You may try this with `Spread` Operator.
If you need to preserve the previous filter value.
other wise you can,

```
this.setState({
    filter: {
          search: "new search", 
          brands: 'value',
          price: 'value'
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let newfilter = Object.assign({}, this.state.filter)

newfilter.search ="value";
newfilter.brands ="value";
newfilter.price ="value";

this.setState({
    filter:newfilter
})
```

Answer (score -5):

You can access the search, brands, price by using:

```
this.setState({
    filter.search = true,
    filter.brands = 'stackoverflow',
    filter.price = 1400
})
```

and to access it, just like usual state access (this.state.filter.search).

Comment: You do not want to directly mutate state like this in React.

Comment: avoid mutate straight to react state